# Override 'Cancel' in event procedures

Tags: forms, vba, excel, ms-word

There is data validation in my MS Word user form which returns the focus to the textbox where the user entered something incorrect. Now I am trying to accommodate the user's change of mind: instead of correcting the entry, I want him to be able to exit the form (click the Exit command button), in which case the entry would be discarded. I suppose that a solution would start with not using the text box's exit event. I little help from someone who knows the answer would save me a lot of testing time, perhaps to find out that I can't do it.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are handling the `Exit` event of the Textbox, setting the `Cancel` output parameter if the data is not valid.

There's a tricky but simple solution that permits to keep that working and still have an Exit button. It permits to activate the handler of the `Exit` button without requiring the focus to leave the Textbox. This way you can unload the Form safely in this handler.

Try this it works pretty smoothly:

1- Set the property `TakeFocusOnClick` of the `Exit` command button to `False`. You can do that at design time in the property-sheet, or at run-time i.e. at `UserForm_Activate`

2- just unload the form when the Exit button is clicked:

```
Private Sub ExitButton_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Your idea saved the day! It wasn't quite what I wanted though, because there are other options that might be clicked, such as "Next" or "Back". I also don't like to unload the form before returning to the procedure that called it. But all of that was easy after you gave the all-important hint. I post the implemented solution below.

Comment: @Variatus *"I also don't like to unload the form before returning to the procedure that called it"*, yes sure, it still needs lot of tweaking. This was only an "idea" but I trust your good practice and common sense to implement it :)

Answer (score 1):

@A.S.H provided the key to the solution below. His point is that it is possible to call another event procedure while `Cancel` is active in the `Exit` procedure of a control. That other procedure can be used to rectify the condition in the first control which is triggering the `Cancel`, thereby enabling an orderly exit. The all-enabling condition is that the control on whose click event the rectifying procedure is to run must not take the focus when clicked (meaning it can run without triggering an exit from the control stuck on `Cancel`). I have added code to the exit procedure to set `CmdExit.TakeFocusOnClick = False` when a `Cancel` condition arises there. Now, ...

```
Private Sub CmdExit_Click()
    ' 12 May 2017

    ' if CmdExit can't take the focus it can't be the ActiveControl
    If Not ActiveControl Is CmdExit Then
        Select Case ActiveControl.Name
            Case "Cbx107"
                Cbx107.Value = ""
            Case "Tbx53"
                Tbx53.Value = "0"
        End Select

        With CmdExit
            If Not .TakeFocusOnClick Then
                .TakeFocusOnClick = True
                .SetFocus
            End If
        End With
    End If

    ' now CmdExit is the ActiveControl
    MsgMe "Cmd Exit: ActiveControl = " & ActiveControl.Name

    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! Would you add some pseudo code for the other procedure?

Comment: @A.S.H. This **is** the "other procedure" announced in my leader. It does as promised. Something I'm missing here?

Comment: Actually, in my project, I placed the entire `IF` statement into a separate function which is called by the exit event procedures of a number of controls, with the control itself passed as an argument.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the Exit event of the Textbox (and other controls) for which you want to validate the data entry, in order to complete the picture. Because I see in this a good "guideline" for similar situations.